# Linux : unable to install kivy in virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, virtualenv, kivy

I am using python2.7 and created a virtual environment 'kivyenv'.
First i install Cython and then kivy in kivyenv.

```
pip install Cython
pip install kivy
```

kivy failed to install giving some error :-

```
In file included from /tmp/pip-build-4T9oG4/kivy/kivy/graphics/opengl.c:274:0:
/tmp/pip-build-4T9oG4/kivy/kivy/graphics/gl_redirect.h:43:22: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
 #   include <GL/gl.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
 error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/root/kivyenv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4T9oG4/kivy/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-3__DxE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers
 /root/kivyenv/include/site/python2.7/kivy" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4T9oG4/kivy/
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Do you have setuptools installed?

Comment: it seems you need OpenGL source code (or at least C/C++ headers *.h) in virtual environment

Comment: any command can i use for installing these ? @furas

Comment: in Ubuntu as always use `apt-get` or `apt` (command line) or `synaptic` (GUI) or `aptitude` (text UI)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you do not have dependency libraries installed on your system, specifically the ones for OpenGL - most likely you do not have mesa packages installed.

Follow the instructions for your specific distribution on how to install all of the needed dependencies at:  https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#using-software-packages

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. the following worked for me:

```
pip(3) install Cython==0.26

pip(3) install kivy
```

hope it helps

Comment: that's why 3 is in brackets. for python 2.7 pip should work just added (3) for anyone who may encounter the problem while using python 3.*